# Getting rows of data with multiple columns condition in R

Tags: r

I have a set of dataset, but I would like to extract rows that contain specific keywords.

I tried using the codes below, and it works. But I just wondering if there is any better way in doing this.

```
test1 <- subset(data, grepl("love|hate", Content))
test2 <- subset(data, grepl("love|hate", Articles))
together <- unique(rbind(test1, test2))
```

I tried combining together, but failed to do so:

```
test1 <- subset(data, grepl("love|hate", Content, Articles))
```

Comment: provide some sample datas..

Comment: You probably need to combine first `Content` and `Articles`, if they are vectors of strings (possibly removing duplicates).

Comment: Try `unique(do.call(rbind, lapply(data[c('Content', 'Articles')], function(x) subset(x, grepl('love|hate', x))))j)`

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here - is it just `subset(data, grepl("love|hate", Content) & grepl("love|hate", Articles) )` ?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) for advice on making good, reproducible questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data[grepl("love|hate",data$Content) & grepl("love|hate",data$Articles),]
```